# how to use chrome devtools protocol for debugging

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/ listed all available devtool protocols chrome uses,but I really have no idea how to use it. Should I set up a websocket server or do anything else? I am a newbee. Please help me?

Comment: The raw protocol is primarily for those who builds debugging tools so it's unlikely you need this info, otherwise you would know how to use it. What do you want to use it for? What is the end/actual/ultimate goal? Why don't you use the built-in devtools in Chrome?

Comment: hello, thank you for your attention. My altimate goal is to create a vscode extension, which can give me information of scopes, closures, lexical environment records and so on. I think vanilla javascript has no way to access these internal properties, so i found devtools protocol and think maybe this can help me

Comment: The exact steps to establish connection are listed in [Using DevTools as protocol client](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/#remote). Then you can fetch `http://localhost:9222/json` and work on targets from there. You'll also probably want to use an abstraction library like the one listed in the "Resources" section of the protocol page.

Comment: What does `Now you can navigate to the given port from your client and attach to any of the discovered tabs for debugging: http://localhost:9222` really mean? I launched a host chrome instance via `chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222` and a client chrome instance via `chrome.exe --user-data-dir=e:ccc`, then i typed `http://localhost:9222` in the client chrome instance, but i get the response of `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. Why this happened?Anything wrong?

Comment: It probably means you need to use a different port number. Look for examples on how to find an available port number for your OS.

Comment: You are so nice ! Thank you :)

Comment: @FranklyCai Man, did you manage to use the CDP?  I already have access to: `http://localhost:9222/json` but I do not understand how to use that info to execute some DOM operations. Any help will be appreciated